# How to Use Null as a value Angular Material Select

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms

I'd like to have a list, where one of the list items is "N/A" and if it is selected, i'd like the formcontrol to have the value null.

In my attempts, I am able to get the formcontrol value to have the value=null but the UI doesnt seem to keep the selected option.

**TS:**

```
import { Component, SimpleChanges, OnChanges } from "@angular/core";
import { FormControl, FormGroup, FormBuilder } from "@angular/forms";

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.scss"]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnChanges {
  mainForm: FormGroup;
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.mainForm = this.fb.group({
      selectedCountryControl: new FormControl("")
    });
  }

  countries: any = [
    {
      full: "Great Britain",
      short: "GB"
    },
    {
      full: "United States",
      short: "US"
    },
    {
      full: "Canada",
      short: "CA"
    },
    {
      full: "N/A",
      short: null
    }
  ];

  submit() {
    console.log(this.mainForm.value);
  }
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<form [formGroup]="mainForm" style="margin-top: 30px;">
    <mat-form-field>
        <mat-select name="countryReactiveVaraible" formControlName="selectedCountryControl" placeholder="Country">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let country of countries" [value]="country.short">
                {{country.full}}
            </mat-option>
        </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>

    <button class="btn btn-primary" mat-button (click)="submit()">
          Save
  </button>
</form>
```

**Behavior:**

[image]

As you can see, I cant seem to make the N/A "stick".

**Stackblitz Link:**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-select-demo-b9fzht?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: it's not a possible thing, because null means actually like it's not selected. `{
      full: "N/A",
      short: ''
    }` - you have to set empty string at least

Answer (score 2):

Set object to value input of mat-select something like this:

**Try this:**

```
<mat-form-field>
        <mat-select #select="matSelect" name="countryReactiveVaraible" formControlName="selectedCountryControl"
            placeholder="Country" [compareWith]="compareFn">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let country of countries" [value]="country">
                {{country.full}}
            </mat-option>
        </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
```

OR

As mentioned by @yurzui you can use set empty string  **'' or -1** to value of short.

```
countries: any = [
    {
      full: "Great Britain",
      short: "GB"
    },
    {
      full: "United States",
      short: "US"
    },
    {
      full: "Canada",
      short: "CA"
    },
    {
      full: "N/A",
      short: ''
    }
  ];
```

[Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-select-demo-ggwnqj)

Comment: In this case he needs to set object as a value to FormControl. mat-select doesn't apply values which are `== null`. In any case it requires some kind of mapping in order to get 'null' for that control as a value.

Comment: What is the better approach ? to use empty string instead of object?

Comment: There is no better approach here. If he just needs to send `null` value to API then he can keep in mind that Angular will do JSON.stringify body and in this case he can do some trick with toJSON method https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-select-demo-nlpxgg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts You can take a look at network tab and notice that we passed `selectedCountryControl: null` to the backend

Comment: And yes, `''` or `-1` values are easier to understand

Comment: Okay Thanks @yurzui, can you please explain,  why const NULL_VALUE return null event though it is object.

Comment: I have found great article  about  that https://thecodebarbarian.com/what-is-the-tojson-function-in-javascript.html Thanks @yurzui, I never knew we could do that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**You can do like this..**

Set `value` of `short` in string like this: **`short: "null"`** and then try it.

> [image: See image]

Comment: But then the form value is also a string: ```{selectedCountryControl: "null"}``` instead of ```{selectedCountryControl: null}```

Comment: Yes I agree, but in other `objects` also `value` is string..

Comment: Per question I want N/A to map to true ```null```